# Why array subscription operator works both ways?

Tags: c++

Why does C++ allow the following statement?

```
  int a[10] = { 0 };
  std::cout << 1[a] << std::endl;
  std::cout << a[1] << std::endl;
```

Both lines print zero and no compiler warning is generated. Shouldn't `1[a]` be illegal as `1` is not an array and `a` is not an integer type.

Code example : http://cpp.sh/4tan

Comment: Because of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Ask the C standard, that's where C++ got its arithmetic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of pointer arithmetic:

```
a[1] == *(a+1) == *(1+a) == 1[a];
```

Quoting the standard (§8.3.4; point 6):

> Except where it has been declared for a class, the subscript operator `[]` is interpreted in such a way that `E1[E2]` is identical to `*((E1)+(E2))`. Because of the conversion rules that apply to `+`, if `E1` is an array and `E2` an integer, then `E1[E2]` refers to the `E2`-th member of `E1`. Therefore, despite its asymmetric appearance, subscripting is a commutative operation.

Note that when you write `a[1]`, the compiler interprets it as `*(a+1)`.  You are still referring the same array `a` when you write `1[a]`, so the compiler is infact still *doing type checking*.

Comment: I get that, but why it doesn't perform any type checking?

Comment: maybe better illustrated with `==`? `assert(a[1] == *(a+1) == *(1+a) == 1[a]);`

Comment: @BatCoder I think OP is assuming `operator[]` is only valid for pointer types, array types and user-defined types that overload the operator. But as shown in the question, it's not.

Comment: @Giuseppe - It *does* type checking. But as `a[b]` is the same as `*(a+b)`, the order of `a` and `b` doesn't matter.

Comment: @GiuseppePes, please check my edit.  Hope this is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine since under the covers it's all just pointer arithmetic. Taking the address of something and adding something else to it (`a[1`) is exactely the same as taking something else and adding an address to it (`1[a]`) - the final address of the object you refer to is the same. One notation is just more intuitive to humans than the other.